# How to create a sequence with single element of sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

To a function I have a parameter which is a [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence).
I would like to return another Sequence (of same type) with single element in the given Sequence.

```py
def get_element_at_index_as_list(some_seq : Sequence, index: int):
    # return some_magic(some_seq[index])
    # s.t. type(some_magic(some_seq[i])) == type(some_seq)
```

Comment: I guess take a slice of length 1 from the sequence. I think that works for normal sequence types.

Comment: Yeah, what @khelwood said. If you `return some_seq[index:index+1]` you will get a string is `some_seq` is a string, a tuple if it's a tuple, etc.

Comment: Please explain where you're stuck.  `Sequence` requires the `index` method.  Doesn't that give you a direct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it should be possible to return a slice of the given sequence.

E.g.

```
return some_seq[index:index+1]
```

as long as the sequence type that you receive supports slicing (and uses objects of its own type for slices). It works for string, list and tuple at least. Even works for `range` objects.

As ShadowRanger points out in a comment, it doesn't work for `collections.deque`, since that does not support slicing. I don't think there is a single way that works for all possible sequence type (especially since users might register their own sequence types).

Here's a way that works for `deque` (and most other sequence types) but does *not* work for string:

```
return type(some_seq)([some_seq[index]])
```

Comment: Slicing works for every built-in (including all modules available in base install) sequence type that I'm aware of with a single glaring exception, `collections.deque`, which has no real reason to omit it aside from `deque`'s mild idiosyncracy of allowing a maximum length, and the lack of agreement on what the semantics of slicing a length-limited `deque` should be (should it lose the limit? keep the limit and silently behave differently from other mutable sequences when you `append` to it later?). `ctypes` arrays and `mmap` won't preserve type though (you get `list` or `bytes` back).

Comment: I was looking for the `return type(some_seq)([some_seq[index]])` as that should work for any sequence that provides conversion from list. 

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_element_at_index_as_list(some_seq : Sequence, index: int):
    return some_seq[index:index+1]
```